# how to append computed value from one excel to another excel with xlrd and xlwt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to read a data from an excel and derived the median, I would like to append this median value as the last row in master.xlsx file, I am new to python, any ideas how to proceed further?

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
import glob
from statistics import median
for xlsxfile in glob.glob('C:\\Temp\\C\\*.xlsx'):
  wb = xlrd.open_workbook(xlsxfile)
wb2=xlrd.open_workbook('C:\\Temp\\D\\master.xlsx')
sheet=wb.sheet_by_index(0)
val=sheet.col_values(0,1,-1)
b = median(val)
print(b)
```

> **Comment**:
>   with openpyxl I am trying now the code is attached herewith

So basically this is the scenario, I was trying to

1. Book_B is the source book, I wanted to calculate the median of a column(Amount), there should not be any range need to specify, because this column will get data for the next week
2. append the median value to Book_A under Values column and it will be repeating every week so it should be a looping 
   Not sure how to calculate the median now and append the data from one excel to another excel.currently the below code is transferring all the data from BOOK_B to BOOK_A

   from openpyxl import load_workbook
   from statistics import median
   source_booklist = ["Book_B.xlsx"]
   target_booklist = load_workbook(filename="Book_A.xlsx",data_only=True)
   for wb in source_booklist:
       book = load_workbook(filename =wb,data_only=True)
       sheet = book['SheetA']
       targetsheet=target_booklist['Sheet1']
       row_count=sheet.max_row
       reportRow = targetsheet.max_row + 1
       print (reportRow)
       column_count=sheet.max_column
       for r in range(1,row_count+1):
               for c in range(1,column_count+1):
                   print (reportRow)
                   source=sheet.cell(row=r, column=c)
                   dest = reportsheet.cell(row=reportRow, column=c)
                   dest.value = source.value
               reportRow += 1
        target_booklist.save("Book_B.xlsx")

Comment: With the modules you have choosen, thats not posible. Read [Working with Excel Files in Python](http://www.python-excel.org/)

Comment: openpyxl I already tried and I was thinking on that but that does not work, that is the reason I was referring to xlrd and xlwt module                             
 So basically this is the scenario, I was trying to append a column from Book_B, I need to compute the median of the column(amount) from the Book_B and I need to append it on the Book_A(Value) column, I also need to get the date having increment of 7 days in the book A under date column, similarly the median value from Book_B should be appended to the Book_A every week along with date incremented for 7 days in Book A.

Comment: As you know what you want to do, [edit] your Question and show your `openpyxl` code, reword the title and add `openpyxl` tag. **Reduce** your code to **ONE** Worksheet example. Please delete the avove comment, [edit] your Question for explanations instead.